# In C++, how can you pass an object's method as a parameter to a function?

Tags: c++, function, methods, parameters

So, I have a function, called Romberg, that takes a function as first parameter:

```cpp
int Romberg(double (*f)(double), ... );
```

When executed, it applies the passed function to several values.

In a class, I have defined the following methods:

```cpp
double Funktion::q(double x){
    return(sqrt(1.0+fd(x)*fd(x)));
};
void Funktion::compute_bogen(){
    Romberg(q, ... );
};
```

Where `fd` is another method from the same class. This however, doesn't work! I tried altering the code in the following way, which ends up with successfully passing the method to the Romberg function; but then it fails to apply the passed function:

```cpp
int Romberg(double (Funktion::* &f)(double), ... );

void Funktion::compute_bogen(){
    Romberg(&Funktion::q, ... );
};
```

I get the following error message:

```cpp
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Right now, I do not see how to make this work without throwing away the whole class system I built.

Comment: The problem is that you also need to pass the instance to call it on.   http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-2-c.html/

Comment: did you try using Romberg as a friend function?

Comment: Can you make your function `f` static or a free function?

Comment: have you looked at specs of std::function? you can give it a pointer-to-class-member, and it stores the object too. 
you would have to rewrite your signature, the rest could stay (mostly) the same.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html

Comment: Does the member function `fd` actually use any data members of the object that it's called on? If not, then you probably *should* throw away the class system that you built, or anyway take `fd` and `q` out of the class (or make them static member functions). Non-static member functions generally should by design be those which access the state of the object.

Comment: @ Kamen The method is public, so I shouldn't need to... i think?  
@ Andrei The problem is, it calls other methods from the same class.
@ Steve It does not. Well, I'm only learning so I guess I might have gone wrong with the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get the following error message:
>
> > error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

This is because `Funktion::q` secretly takes 2 arguments, a `this` pointer and the `double`

The problem is that `Romberg` doesn't have any information about the object that calls it in `Funktion::compute_bogen()`, so it can't give it to `Funktion::q()`.  You probably want something like this:

```
typedef double (Funktion::*RombergFuncArg)(double)

int
Romberg(RombergFuncArg func, Funktion& obj, ... )
{
   double input  = 0.0;
   double output = (obj.*func)(input);
   //...
}
```

[Edit] In reply to the comment:

```
void Funktion::compute_bogen(){
   Romberg(&Funktion::q, *this, ... );
};
```

Comment: And how would I need to call the `Romberg` function?

Answer (score 1):

To make it work with your class system, you need to define `fd` to take a pointer to a member function instead of a pointer to a function (the two are *not* the same).

Then you'll need to invoke it correctly for a pointer to a member function as well (which is slightly different than invoking a pointer to a function).

I'd note that although you can do this, you might be better off considering a somewhat different structure. One that's fairly common is to use a virtual function, which you'll override in various derived classes. Then instead of using a pointer to a member function, you select the object that implements the function you want, and invoke the virtual function in that object.